# Can't install Packet Tracer 7.3 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: cisco

I'm new here, i don't really know that much about Linux, but today I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC and i searched for the 7.3 version of Packet Tracer, and i installed the .deb file, extracted it and got my files. There is one problem: once I try to run the program (by the terminal, writing:

```
cd /opt/pt
./PacketTracer7
), i always get a different type of error, always reguarding my libraries. So i searched for an answer and found that command:
ldd PacketTracer7
that shows me the missing directories that Packet Tracer actually needs, and this came out:

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff52599000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f8f588c6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8f588a3000)
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007f8f5878c000)
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f8f58745000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f8f586cc000)
    libQt5Svg.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007f8f58670000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f8f57fd3000)
    libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (0x00007f8f51323000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f8f50d38000)
    libQt5WebSockets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebSockets.so.5 (0x00007f8f50d01000)
    libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (0x00007f8f50cde000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8f50b1d000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007f8f50ad9000)
    libQt5Script.so.5 => not found
    libQt5ScriptTools.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f8f50a8b000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8f50542000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8f50361000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8f50210000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8f501f5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8f50003000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8f4fffd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8f5e663000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f8f4ffa8000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f8f4facf000)
    libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f8f4fab6000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8f4fa9a000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007f8f4fa09000)
    libicui18n.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66 (0x00007f8f4f70a000)
    libicuuc.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007f8f4f524000)
    libnss3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f8f4f3d3000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f8f4f3a0000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f8f4f360000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8f4f332000)
    libevent-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7 (0x00007f8f4f2dc000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f8f4f2a4000)
    libwebpmux.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpmux.so.3 (0x00007f8f4f098000)
    libwebpdemux.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.2 (0x00007f8f4ee93000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f8f4ec2a000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f8f4eb6b000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f8f4eae6000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f8f4ea9f000)
    libre2.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libre2.so.5 (0x00007f8f4ea2c000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007f8f4ea21000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f8f4e91c000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8f4e7df000)
    libXss.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f8f4e7da000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f8f4e6df000)
    libavcodec.so.58 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58 (0x00007f8f4d120000)
    libavformat.so.58 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58 (0x00007f8f4cea8000)
    libavutil.so.56 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56 (0x00007f8f4cd7f000)
    libvpx.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.6 (0x00007f8f4cb47000)
    libopus.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f8f4cae8000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f8f4ca97000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f8f4c8db000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f8f4c899000)
    libminizip.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminizip.so.1 (0x00007f8f4c68e000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f8f4c633000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8f4c5ab000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f8f4c0ca000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f8f4c047000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007f8f4c031000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f4bf08000)
    libpulsecommon-13.99.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so (0x00007f8f4be86000)
    libicudata.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007f8f4a3c3000)
    libplc4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f8f4a3bc000)
    libplds4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f8f4a3b7000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f8f4a3ae000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f8f4a381000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8f4a355000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f8f4a340000)
    libswresample.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.3 (0x00007f8f4a31e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f8f4a2f5000)
    librsvg-2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2 (0x00007f8f499ca000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f4996a000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f8f49845000)
    libzvbi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007f8f497b6000)
    libaom.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaom.so.0 (0x00007f8f49318000)
    libcodec2.so.0.9 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcodec2.so.0.9 (0x00007f8f48534000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f8f48525000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f8f484ad000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007f8f48455000)
    libshine.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007f8f4824a000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f8f4822c000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f8f481ef000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f8f481cf000)
    libtwolame.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x00007f8f481a9000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f8f48179000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f8f480ce000)
    libwavpack.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x00007f8f480a2000)
    libx264.so.155 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.155 (0x00007f8f47de4000)
    libx265.so.179 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.179 (0x00007f8f46e76000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f8f46d63000)
    libva.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.2 (0x00007f8f46d38000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f8f46d25000)
    libgme.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007f8f46cd8000)
    libopenmpt.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 (0x00007f8f46aeb000)
    libchromaprint.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libchromaprint.so.1 (0x00007f8f46ad5000)
    libbluray.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.2 (0x00007f8f46a82000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f8f468ac000)
    libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x00007f8f46820000)
    libva-drm.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.2 (0x00007f8f4681b000)
    libva-x11.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2 (0x00007f8f46813000)
    libvdpau.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1 (0x00007f8f4680d000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f8f467f7000)
    libOpenCL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007f8f465ec000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f8f4653d000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f8f46485000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f8f46451000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f8f463dc000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f8f463d0000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f8f46353000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f8f4614d000)
    libapparmor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1 (0x00007f8f46138000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8f4612d000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8f46125000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8f4611d000)
    libsoxr.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007f8f460b2000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f8f460a6000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f4607e000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f45e9b000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f45e89000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f45e3a000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f8f45e2e000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f8f45d87000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f8f45d82000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f8f45d71000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f8f45b67000)
    libogg.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f8f45b5a000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f8f45b4d000)
    libmpg123.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpg123.so.0 (0x00007f8f45aed000)
    libvorbisfile.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0x00007f8f45ae0000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f8f459aa000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f8f45989000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f8f45807000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f8f457f1000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f8f457b5000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f8f4577d000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f8f456f9000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f8f455db000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f8f455b8000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f8f4556b000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f8f45561000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f8f45540000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f8f45523000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f8f454e5000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8f454c9000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f8f454ad000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f8f4546b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f45465000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f8f45405000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f8f453da000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f453bf000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f8f453a2000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f8f45397000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f8f452ba000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f8f45289000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f8f45280000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f8f45271000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f8f4521a000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f8f4518a000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f8f45180000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f8f45177000)
```

What's the problem? Why do i miss so many libraries? How can I install them? Do i have to install them one by one?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Packet tracer can be a huge hassle to install because of all the dependencies.

My preferred method is using this script:
https://github.com/Retinazer/packettracer-installer

Just a heads-up, Cisco just released packet tracer 8 :)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you need for those two files they are in the libqt5script5 & libqt5scripttools5 packages on my Kubuntu 20.10. The apt-file is a wonderful little program that allows you to find the package containing the files needed for just this idea.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:~# apt-file search libQt5Script
libqt5script5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so.5
libqt5script5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so.5.14
libqt5script5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so.5.14.2
libqt5scripttools5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.so.5
libqt5scripttools5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.so.5.14
libqt5scripttools5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.so.5.14.2
nsight-compute: /usr/lib/nsight-compute/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/libQt5Script.so.5
nsight-systems: /usr/lib/nsight-systems/host-linux-x64/libQt5Script.so.5
qtscript5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-          gnu/libQt5Script.prl
qtscript5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so
qtscript5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.prl
qtscript5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.so
```